# Open gwt submenu direction depending on window boundaries

Tags: gwt, browser, menubar

I am creating a vertical gwt menubar and I am wonder if there is a way to detect the browser window boundary. I want to open a sub menu on the right (as its natural) if it doesn't cause it to go wider than the bounds of the browser window, otherwise I want to open to the left. Is there a way to programmatically know the bounds of the browser window to achieve this functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Window.getClientWidth()` and `Window.getClientHeight()` to get the window boundaries.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to figure it out from there